# Seeking X-Men issue number from 1980s with quote from either Wolverine or Storm

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men

In one X-Men comic in the 1980s, Kitty Pryde was having trouble in her relationship with Wolverine. She confided in Storm, and Storm offered less solace than expected. Part of Storm's response was:

> "Ultimately, we live our lives alone."

I may have the roles of Storm and Wolverine reversed; that is, Kitty may have been confiding in Wolverine about her troubles with Storm. It has been so long I have forgotten.

I *think* the issue I'm asking about comes **before** [the first Brood saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brood_(comics)#History) – around #165 on Jan 1983 – but I'm not even sure about that. If I'm correct, that means the issue I'm seeking would be between [129](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_129) and [162](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/13703/uncanny_x-men_1963_162).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be thinking of a scene in Uncanny X-Men #151.

In this issue, it's not an issue with Wolverine, or Storm, themselves, but rather that Kitty's parents have withdrawn her from Xavier's school (to place her in the Hellfire Club's Massachusetts Academy).  She's naturally upset about the thought of losing all her friends and having to go be in a school run by evil supervillains (and how her parents have changed so suddenly and not caring about her wishes), and sulks in her room alone.

Storm goes to comfort her, and as you remember, it's not, initially, a very comforting message.

[image]

Though by the end she does seem at least a little comforted, if nothing else by Ororo's presence being there.

Comment: Wow my memory is bad! When I read what you wrote about parents it suddenly rang a bell. Give me a few days to let this sink in before I accept answer. I have already upvoted tho.